# IIS Subdomain Host Headers Not Working

Tags: iis-7, dns, subdomain

Using IIS 7, I have an existing website, example.com, and I have added another website to which I'd like the URL, sub.example.com to point. I've set up the host headers for this, but it does not work. Trying to ping the subdomain URL give the message "Ping request could not find host sub.example.com. Please check the name and try again."

Should a DNS setting perhaps be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subdomain must be set in the DNS or it will not resolve to an IP address. Just having it defined in IIS is not enough. The client computer must be able to translate the name into a meaningful server address.

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same problem. Could you elaborate a bit how this is done?

Comment: It depends on how your domain name is served. Some hosting providers don't allow this sort of subdomain definition. If you work for a company that manages its own DNS, you would need to request your networking department add the subdomain attached to the IP of your website. Once the traffic is redirected, your IIS server should pick  it up.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was forwarding the subdmain, which was not understood by iis. I should have used CName all way along. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378228/how-to-set-hostheader-correctly-for-subdomains/8383923#8383923