# How to set hostHeader correctly for subdomains?

Tags: iis, iis-7, azure, dns, subdomain

I have created a two sites like this:

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="WebRole" physicalDirectory="./WebRole">
    <Bindings>
         <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="HttpEndpoint" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>   
  <Site name="MySite" physicalDirectory="./MySite">         
      <Bindings>                     
         <Binding name="Endpoint" endpointName="HttpEndpoint"  hostHeader="www.MySite.com"/>                    
      </Bindings>     
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

I have changed my DNS under CNAME (Alias) -> www to xxx.cloudapp.net

Therefore when I type in www.MySite.com it gets to my cloud app, the hostHeader is recognized and goes to the right physical site. The HostHeader works fine.

Now I try to do the same thing as a subdomain.

```
<Site name="MySite" physicalDirectory="./MySite">       
        <Bindings>                   
            <Binding name="Endpoint" endpointName="HttpEndpoint"  hostHeader="sub.MySite.com"/>                     
        </Bindings>       
</Site>
```

In DNS manager I didn't try to do it in CNAME but instead I did a masked Forward of the sub domain to the same side's address xxx.cloudapp.net.

But this doesn't work. It simply open up the first Site instead. It seems the HostHeader is not understood in order to point to the second physical path.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think the masking is the issue. How did you set the masking? Check with fiddler what happens when you try to hit your subdomain. Why didn't you use CNAME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell "masked forwarding" usually works by using frames, and if that's the case the host header information won't be forwarded to Azure.

Your DNS host will create a Web site with a frame, and the data for that frame will come from the xxx.cloudapp.net site. As there's no host header information forwarded the Azure load balancer won't be able to use the alternate site.

I'm afraid it looks like you'll need to use the CNAME system to explicitly forward the host names.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. After putting up the question here, I realized it must have to do something with forwarding. I managed to simply enter the subdomain's name as a CName and forwarded it to the xxx.cloudapp.net. Now my subdomain works.  Its best to avoid forwarding altogether.